# How to convert column into date format in R that has extra information

Tags: r, regex, date, gsub

I would like to use some sort of regex function for the rest of the data (~2 million rows) to extract relevant date information (ideally have Day, Month, and time in date format since Year is only 2009 for ~2 million rows).

I have a column that looks like so:

```
ID | created_at
1    Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009
2    Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009
```

I applied these two functions to extract "day" and delete 'PDT 2009' from the end but now I would like to make the rest of the columns be date format for plotting purposes.

```
df$Day <- sub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", df$created_at) ## Extract first word

df$delete <- gsub("\\PDT.*","", df$created_at) ## Delete everything after PDT starts
```

Desired outcome:

```
ID | created_at                    | Month  | Day  | Time
1    Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009    Apr      Mon    22:19:45
2    Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009    Apr      Mon    22:19:49
```

Comment: "I would like to make the rest of the columns be _date_ format" - but none of your desired columns are of a standard date format, i.e. year-month-day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach using `str_split` in companion with `map_char`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(elements = str_split(created_at, fixed(" "), n=6)) %>% 
    mutate(Month = map_chr(elements, 2),
           Day = map_chr(elements, 1),
           Time = map_chr(elements, 4), .keep="unused"
           )
```

output:

```
  ID                   created_at Month Day     Time
1  1 Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009   Apr Mon 22:19:45
2  2 Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009   Apr Mon 22:19:49
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use any regexes, just regular date formatting is sufficient. you can find a nice overview [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/dates.html) or in `?strptime()`. You just have to adjust for the separators. This should be easier and more efficient than using regexes, splitting, etc...

Once you have this in native R DateTime formats `POSIXlt` and `POSIXt`, you can easily extract all date-related information.

```
strptime(x      = "Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009",
         format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PDT %Y")
#> [1] "2009-04-06 22:19:45 CEST"
```

Comment: Excellent alternative and I am not familiar with strptime - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution too:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number(), 
         Month = gsub("(?:[A-Za-z]+)\\s([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", created_at, perl = TRUE),
         Day = gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", created_at, perl = TRUE), 
         Time = gsub(".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*", "\\1", created_at, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  relocate(ID)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     ID created_at                   Month Day   Time    
  <int> <chr>                        <chr> <chr> <chr>   
1     1 Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009 Apr   Mon   22:19:45
2     2 Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009 Apr   Mon   22:19:49
```

Comment: Appreciate the use of gsub and see it as that - thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just after `Month`, `Day`, and `Time`, why not use `extract` from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(col = created_at, 
          into = c('Month', 'Day', 'Time'), 
          regex = "([A-Za-z]+)\\s([A-Za-z]+)\\s\\d{2}\\s([\\d:]+)")
  Month Day     Time
1   Mon Apr 22:19:45
2   Mon Apr 22:19:49
```

Here, we define three capturing groups using the round brackets syntax `(...)` to identify the substrings we want to `extract` into the three columns.

If you also need `created_at`in its original form, just store the results as, say, `df1` and use `cbind`:

```
cbind(df, df1)
                    created_at Month Day     Time
1 Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009   Mon Apr 22:19:45
2 Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009   Mon Apr 22:19:49
```

Data:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    created_at = c("Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009","Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009") 
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

### Data

```
df <- 
  tibble(
    created_at = c("Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009","Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009") 
  )
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  separate(
    col = created_at,
    into = c("wday","month","day","time","type","year"),
    sep = " ",
    remove = FALSE
    ) %>% 
  mutate(
    day = as.numeric(day),
    year = as.numeric(year),
    month_num = which(month.abb == month),
    time = hms(time),
    date = lubridate::make_date(year = year,month = month_num,day = day)
  )
```

### Results

```
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  created_at                   wday  month   day time        type   year month_num date      
  <chr>                        <chr> <chr> <dbl> <Period>    <chr> <dbl>     <int> <date>    
1 Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009 Mon   Apr       6 22H 19M 45S PDT    2009         4 2009-04-06
2 Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT 2009 Mon   Apr       6 22H 19M 49S PDT    2009         4 2009-04-06
```